# Finding a continuous function to solve the following optimization problem.

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, optimization, calculus-of-variations

Suppose you have a compact set $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ partitioned as $\Omega = \bigcup_{j=1}^n \Omega_j$ with that $\Omega_i  \cap \Omega_j = \emptyset$ if $i \neq j$. Define for $y_1,\ldots y_n \in \mathbb{R}$

$$
s = \sum_{j=1}^n y_j \chi_{A_j}
$$

(Essentially a simple function on $\Omega$). I was wondering if there's. Suppose also $m$ is the Lebeasgue measure. I wonder if the following problem

$$
E(f) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{\Omega} (f-s)^2dm
$$

Has solution with $f$ continuous. A first attempt I did was to use the Euler Lagrange equations, but this gives me $f = s$ which isn't necessarily continuous. Apart from this attempt I believe I could for example use the Stone-Weirstrass theorem, which would give me a dense subspace in $C(\Omega)$ and maybe look for the solution there. I think however I can still use the Euler Lagrange equations somewhat but maybe I need to better impose the constraint like

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
\text{minimize} \;E(f) \\
s.t. \;\;f \in C(\Omega)
\end{array}
\right.
$$

But I cannot think of a way (at least amongs the tools I know) that would enable me to solve the problem.

Can anyone suggest something to look up maybe?

Comment: Well in general you cannot find a continuous minimizer. The fact that a solution may not exist is no different from any minimization problem. I'm not sure why you think there is a minimizer?

Comment: Well if define $X_n = \text{span}\left\{1,\ldots,x^n \right\}$ I can find the minimizer for sure by using multivariable calculus for every $n$. So I guess that due to weirstrass approximation theorem I can get a sequence approximating the continuous function I want? If there's a specific reason why a minimizer can't be found I'd like to know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can approximate $s$ arbitrarily by a continuous piecewise linear function. for instance, let the function be $y_j$ on $\Omega_j$ except on an arbitrarily small subset of it so that it can jump linearly into the other $y_j$'s (this is not rigorous but you should be able to make this more precise; this is just an outline). So the infimum of $E$ is $0$. Now suppose there exists a continuous $f$ such that $E(f) = 0$. This would imply $f=s$ almost everywhere. Reorder the $y_j's$ s.t. $y_1\le y_2 \le...\le y_n$. At least two of them are not equal (otherwise s would be continuous). WLOG name them $y_1$ and $y_2$. Then for $\epsilon$ small enough $f^{-1}((y_1+\epsilon,y_2-\epsilon))$ is an open set by continuity of $f$ and hence the integral over this set of $(f-s)^2$ is strictly positive, leading to a contradiction. Note that I assumed $f$ attains the value of $y_1$ and $y_2$ (hence the above open set is nonempty by the intermediate value theorem) since $f$ must equal $s$ almost everywhere and I'm assuming $\Omega_j$'s have positive measure. If they do not I leave it to you to modify the argument.

Comment: I am not sure what you proved. Looks like you've shown there's no continuous function $f$ equal to $s$. Which is ok. But I think you can find the best approximant somewhat?

Comment: I proved that no minimizer exists and there is no "best approximant" since you can approximate it arbitrarily well. Think of it as the following: Suppose you are trying to minimize the function $f(x)=x^2$ on $(0,1)$. Notice that the infimum is exactly $0$ since you can make that function arbitrarily small but never quite achieve $0$ since $0$ is not in your domain. Hence there exists no minimizer. this is exactly the case here. You can make a continuous function that it as close as you like to $s$ but a minimum doesn't exist since if it does, it wouldn't be continuous as I have shown.

Comment: Can this argument be justfied maybe in terms of compact set? or dense set? My idea is that my $E$ is a functional which is essentially the $L^2$ norm squared, but I am defining such a function in $C(\Omega)$ which is dense in $L^2$ w.r.t. the $L^2$ metric. So I don't know if there's an explanation of non existance of minimizers in terms of such concept maybe.

Comment: The key issue here is that even though $C(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^2$ it's not a complete subspace, hence a minimizer may not exist (and indeed, it doesn't). There is a theorem which does guarantee existence of such a minimizer, it's called the "Hilbert projection theorem" and says that a minimizer to your functional would exist if you take your space of functions to be a complete convex subset of $L^2$

Comment: Where "complete convex subset means"? Does "complete" means "cauchy sequences are convergent"?

Comment: Yes, complete as in a complete metric space. So if you have a convex subset which is also a complete metric space (where the metric is the norm coming from the inner product), then you have your minimizer. $C(\Omega)$ is not such a subset.

Comment: Not under the $L^2$ norm, but it is under the sup norm. If I used such a norm to minimize the same functional (but I won't be able to through the EL equations I assume) would it work?

Comment: Well, first of all, $s$ would not be an element of your space hence you would not be minimizing any sort of norm between elements, so you wouldn't even be able to formulate such a problem. But even more-so, the projection theorem doesn't just rely on the completeness of the subspace and convexity but also, crucially, on the inner product structure which the space of continuous function with sup norm lack. More generally, I believe the HPT is true for reflexive Banach spaces, but even then, the space of continuous functions with sup norm is not reflexive.

Comment: Ok, I see. I'll give it a bit more thought.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no one function giving the infimum, but based on Proposition 22, Chapter 3, Section 5 of Royden's: Real Analysis anf Exercice 15, Chapter 4 of this book, we can find for every $\epsilon >0$ (since s(.) is bounded measurable) a continuous function such that :

$\int _{\Omega}\left| f(x)-s(x)\right| dx\,<\,\epsilon$.

Therefore there is a sequence $f_{n}$ of continuous functions such

that $\,\,E(f_{n})\,\to\,0$, BUT there is not ONE continuous function

$f$ achieving the infimum!!

Take as an example $s(x)=0$ on

$[0,1)$ and $s(x)=1$ on $[1,2]$. It is clear that there is NO

continuous function giving $E(f)=0$ but $inf_{f}\,E(f)=0$ !!